# Modify a const char parameter

Tags: c++, char, constants

I am currently programming a function which should save a number of characters to a const char*, which is a parameter to the function. The overall functionality is given and I cannot change the parameters. Something along the lines of:

```cpp
bool charChange(const char* array, uint32_t length)
{
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i<length; i++){
    int32_t nextChar = getChar(); //Get next character. Needs to be signed int, for other logic
    array[i] = (char) nextChar;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Some of the logic is left out for clarity, but this should highlight the problem.
I have tried all sorts of dark magic, but I cannot figure out how to pass the characters to the const char array parameter. Tbh. it doesn't even make sense that this would be doable.

Comment: If you're supposed top change the contents of the `char` array, why are you passing it in as `const char *` to begin with? That just doesn't make sense. What is your actual assignment? What does your teacher say when you ask him or her?

Comment: please show a [mre], you fundamentally can't change the contents of `array`, its a constant

Comment: @AlanBirtles It is worth noting Ted's answer: You can change it if the underlying object is not const.

Comment: What do you think "const" means? Maybe it means it should NOT be modified? Remove "const" from you function argument if you want to change it OR return a copy.  By the a char array is probably better modeled as a `std::string`

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you understood the assignment/task/interface correctly? If anyone intended the interface to be used the way you describe it, that seems like a serious lapse of judgement on their behalf.

Comment: *Tbh. it doesn't even make sense that this would be doable.*  It is doable (as per Ted's answer), but it's super dangerous.  Any cast is telling the compiler "I know you think this is wrong, but it's not wrong, and I know what I'm doing, so just do it anyway" — but in my experience, usually the compiler is right and the cast is wrong.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yes, you can use `const_cast`, you can also use `delete` on something not allocated by `new`. I've yet to come across many uses for `const_cast` in real code and this doesn't seem like one of them

Comment: @AlanBirtles There is a huge difference: `delete`ing something not allocated via `new` is *always* UB. By contrast, writing to an object through a pointer to `const` is only UB if the underlying object is indeed constant. To re-iterate: **There are legitimate and conforming use cases of writing to values declared `const`.**

Comment: This [gotcha of the week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm) is relevant. Bottom line: Const declarations are primarily an aid for *humans*, not for compilers. A compiler can only be sure that nobody "secretly" writes to a const elsewhere if it can see the all places of usage (e.g. during whole program optimization. or because all the code is visible in the translation unit); and then it actually doesn't need the const any longer because it can *prove* the object is never written to.

Comment: I know the task is stupid, but here's the (translated) extract from the task:
_Parameters:_
`const char *receive`: _Pointer to the array, in which the message shall be saved._

Comment: I would also like to add that this is a University I'm studying at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's utterly confusing to have a function that is supposed to mutate the input take the input as `const`. It does not make sense.

Anyway, you can cast away `const` with `const_cast`:

```cpp
bool charChange(const char* array, uint32_t length) {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int32_t nextChar = getChar();
        const_cast<char*>(array)[i] = static_cast<char>(nextChar);
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oW3PbY4T3)

Note: If the actual array you pass into this function was declared `const`, this will have undefined behavior.